# How to insert empty values into Marklogic database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Our application have some optional field like quantity where I need not have a value, but when I insert into Marklogic database without an value for an attribute it fails. Is there a function where I leave a particular attribute blank(without value)?

I am getting the below error:

```
[javascript] JS-JAVASCRIPT: "FundDANADayCountQuantity": , -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

since it is seeing the "Comma" as there is no value
I have not created any index as of now. For the time being I have used -1 to test the data.

Thanks,
Bharath

Comment: How does the insert fail? What error are you seeing?

Comment: Do you have a range index on this field? If so, you may want to try inserting a value of 0 instead of an empty string or null value.

Comment: What happens if you omit the optional attribute, instead of creating with an empty value? It would be helpful if you provided more details, such as the error message, any relevant log events from the ErrorLog, information about any range indexes, etc.

Comment: Very useful would be snippet of the document and API your calling - Is this JSON or XML  or RDF ? in-server ? client code ? Java ? Python? JavaScript ? XQuery?

Comment: Showing more code would help. Could you edit your question to share more detail? I would consider using `null` instead of `-1`, but not sure how well that would work in your case..